# How to fix an issue "The following environment does not have an entry for the variable x"?

Tags: drake

I find the previous answer in Eric Boehlke's question can't solve my problem.
When I try to inverse a matrix contain symbolic variable which is the output of ManipulatorDynamics(), an runtime error"The following environment does not have an entry for the variable x" happen.
I test is in a simple example, the error is the same. Here is the code.
Please tell me how to solve, thank you very much!

```
from pydrake.all import Variable
from pydrake.all import MultibodyPlant
from underactuated import ManipulatorDynamics
import pydrake.symbolic as sym
import numpy as np

plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0)
parser = Parser(plant)
parser.AddModelFromFile(FindResource("models/double_pendulum.urdf"))
plant.Finalize()

# Evaluate the dynamics symbolically
q = [sym.Variable("x"), sym.Variable("y")]
v = [sym.Variable("xd"), sym.Variable("yd")]
(M, Cv, tauG, B, tauExt) = ManipulatorDynamics(plant.ToSymbolic(), q, v)
p = sym.inv(M)
```

Comment: Why do you want to take the inverse of M?  (this might be made to work for the double pendulum, but is not a road to happiness for more complex systems)  If you want to write a constraint with the manipulator dynamics, I recommend writing it in implicit form:  e.g Mvdot + Cv = tauG + B*u + tauExt, instead of vdot = inv(M)*[tauG + ... ].

Comment: I try to apply the iLQR example to a multibody system.  The iLQR example is in underactuated/exercise/trajopt/ilqr_driving. It need to derive Jacobian of dynamic(f_x, f_u).  Then I need explicit form of Xd.

Comment: Yes, it already takes over several hours to inverse a 8x8 matrix ( Not yet complete.)  I will save/load the inverse-matrix result to reduce the running time.  Does it make sense?

Comment: To obtain the iLQR working, you do not need the symbolic form of the dynamics. You only need the numerical values of the Jacobian. It is almost always much faster to compute the Jacobian in numerical value directly (in this case maybe through automatic differentiation), than computing the symbolic form first, and then evaluate the symbolic form.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit confusing here. Based on comments in the code, symbolic matrix inversion fails for matrices larger than 4x4.